# XAML navigation in Windows Store Grid App

Tags: xaml, c#-4.0, windows-8, grid, windows-store-apps

I trying to navigate between XAML pages in grid app. for this i have added a added a new XAML and a button in XAML and cs code for button event is

```
   private void OnClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
   {
     Frame.Navigate(typeof (GroupedItemsPage));
   }
```

on clicking this button my app should navigate to GroupedItemsPage, but instead it raises an null exception

Answer (score 1):

try this :

```
 private void OnClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
 {
     this.Frame.Navigate(typeof (GroupedItemsPage));
 }
```

Please have a look [there](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/hh771188.aspx), too.

Comment: thanks, but i tried out this but it works fine with normal app but when i use same for grid app a null reference exception is raised and msdn article u mentioned also explains for normal app only.